# Is there a simple way to do for loops in BigQuery for querying multiple tables?

Tags: sql, for-loop, google-bigquery

I recently did a data analysis project in BigQuery that analyzes multiple NOAA GHCN (climate data) tables over many years of data. I used Python in Colab to be able to do this with this code

```
"""
This code loops over each year from 1990 to 2022 (inclusive), constructs a SQL query to retrieve the temperature data for that year, executes the query using the BigQuery client, and appends the resulting data to an overall DataFrame. 
The query retrieves the temperature data for the Burning Man event (identified by the station ID 'USC00264527') for the 9 days leading up to and including Labor Day, which is the duration of the event. 
The data is returned in Fahrenheit degrees, converted from Celsius degrees. The resulting DataFrame will contain temperature data for each year of the Burning Man event.
"""

# Create an empty DataFrame to hold the temperature data
dfall = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop over years from 1990 to 2022 (inclusive)
for i in range(1990, 2023):
  
   # Construct a SQL query to retrieve temperature and rain data for the year
   sql = (
       f"WITH labor_day AS ("
       f"SELECT MIN(date) date "
       f"FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_{i}` "
       f"WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 9 AND EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM date) = 2"
       f"),"
       f"distinct_dates AS ("
       f"SELECT DISTINCT ghcnd.date, "
       f"EXTRACT(DAYOFYEAR FROM ghcnd.date) dayofyear, "
       f"EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ghcnd.date) yearstring, "
       f"DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ghcnd.date ASC) AS day "
       f"FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_{i}` ghcnd "
       f"INNER JOIN labor_day ON ghcnd.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(labor_day.date, INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND labor_day.date "
       f"ORDER BY date "
       f")"
       f"SELECT a.id, "
       f"a.date, "
       f"a.element, "
       f"CASE "
       f"WHEN a.element IN ('TMAX', 'TMIN') THEN (a.value/10 * 1.8) + 32 "
       f"WHEN a.element = 'PRCP' THEN a.value/10 "
       f"END AS value, "
       f"b.dayofyear, "
       f"b.yearstring, "
       f"b.day "
       f"FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_{i}` a "
       f"JOIN distinct_dates b ON a.date = b.date "
       f"WHERE id = 'USC00264527' "
       f"AND a.element IN ('TMAX', 'TMIN', 'PRCP') "
       f"ORDER BY date ASC"
   )
  
   # Print the SQL query for debugging purposes
   print(sql)
  
   # Execute the query using the BigQuery client and convert the result to a Pandas DataFrame
   dfyear = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
  
   # Append the temperature data for the year to the overall DataFrame
   dfall = pd.concat([dfall, dfyear], ignore_index=True)

   # Print the shape of the overall DataFrame to track the progress of the loop
   print(dfall.shape)
```

Is there a way to natively do this sort of looping in BigQuery? Would be nice to not always have to use Python for this sort of thing. thanks

Comment: I can't help but think that it would be better to union your `bigquery_public_data.ghcn_{year}` tables into a single derived table and query that all at once instead of making multiple round trips back to your data.

Comment: is there a simple way to do that without having to hard code 30+ table names?

Comment: You could dynamically write out the Union SQL inside the for loop, and the remaining  bits outside the for loop.

Comment: aha, I meant in SQL, not Python

Comment: No. There is "loop" in sql, except in a stored procedure, but for this usecase, if you are interested in trying out a union approach, then it's 1:1 with Python.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this doesn't answer your "Do this without python question". Unfortunately there is no way outside of a stored procedure to implement a loop (either to select many times for each individual table) or to write the sql dynamically and then execute (as we do here in python)

Here's what this would look like taking the UNION approach, writing dynamically in python, if it's of any interest.

I moved the filters up into the UNION select statements so the union'd result set stays small. I also added in a column for the `year` for each table into the result set so you know the source table from which the row originated:

```
sql = "WITH ghcn_union AS (\n"
# Loop over years from 1990 to 2022 (inclusive)
sql += "UNION ALL".join([f" SELECT {i} as yr, id, date, element, value FROM bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_{i} WHERE id = 'USC00264527' AND a.element IN ('TMAX', 'TMIN', 'PRCP')\n" for i in range(1990, 2023)])
sql += """)
WITH labor_day AS (
        SELECT yr, MIN(date) date
        FROM ghcn_union
        WHERE EXTRACT(
                    MONTH
                    FROM date
                ) = 9
                AND EXTRACT(
                    DAYOFWEEK
                    FROM date
                ) = 2
        GROUP BY yr
),
distinct_dates AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ghcnd.date,
                EXTRACT(
                    DAYOFYEAR
                    FROM ghcnd.date
                ) dayofyear,
                EXTRACT(
                    YEAR
                    FROM ghcnd.date
                ) yearstring,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY ghcnd.date ASC
                ) AS day
        FROM ghcn_union ghcnd
                INNER JOIN labor_day 
                    ON ghcnd.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(labor_day.date, INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND labor_day.date                     
        ORDER BY date
)
SELECT a. yr,
        a.id,
        a.date,
        a.element,
        CASE
                WHEN a.element IN ('TMAX', 'TMIN') THEN (a.value / 10 * 1.8) + 32
                WHEN a.element = 'PRCP' THEN a.value / 10
        END AS value,
        b.dayofyear,
        b.yearstring,
        b.day
FROM ghcn_union a
        JOIN distinct_dates b ON a.date = b.date
ORDER BY date ASC"""
```

Ran this locally and the sql looks good. Definitely give it a solid peer review before letting it run loose in your database.